# Bootstrap enlarge picture to take up entire column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I have a row with 1 column and another row with 2 columns.
All items have one picture in it, and should take up all the avaible space inside the column.
So far I can't get the first image on the first row to fill the div width,this image resizes correctly when I reduce the window, but when I enlarge it, the picture will 
resize to its original maximum size when I want it to be always same as the div width

Here is the snippet : https://jsfiddle.net/gd0obgg9/

Here is the code :

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Portfolio Item
            </h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div></div>
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/550x200" alt="">
         </div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <hr>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I want my 550x200 to fill enterely the width 
Any advice ? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, to give the image full width use:

```
.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note that this will, in some cases, distort the image to cover the full `div`

In my test:
[image: fullwidth]

Comment: add another class like .max-width{ width: 100%; }. You might need .img-responsive as it is for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Update your css to set the width of `img` elements inside your columns to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `width:100%` to your img

here the new code

```
<body>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Portfolio Item Heading -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Portfolio Item
                    <small>Item Subheading</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Portfolio Item Row -->
        <div class="row">
<div>

</div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" src="http://placehold.it/550x200" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>

</div>


        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Related Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">

            <hr>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>



        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```